# AngularJS unable to get auth object from service in a resolve function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, resolve

I need to fetch some data before allowing the page to render so that the page isn't empty for a second before showing the info. But I'm unable to get my resolve to work.

The issue is that the `uid` line throws an error because `states.getAuth()` is undefined. `states.getAuth()` should (and does) return authentication info about the user when using it from my controllers but when using it in this resolve it doesn't for some reason.

Am I going about this completely wrong? I have never had to do a resolve like this before so I wouldn't know so some guidance would be great.

Let me know if I have to include any of my services or if this route snippet is enough to figure out a solution.

```
.when('/programs/:program', {
  templateUrl: 'views/pages/single-program.html',
  resolve: {
    'isAuth': ['fbRefs', function(fbRefs) {
      return fbRefs.getAuthObj().$requireAuth();
    }],
    'programData': ['$route', 'fbRefs', 'states', function($route, fbRefs, states) {

      // Get our program key from $routeParams
      var key = $route.current.params.program;

      // Get unique user id
      var uid = states.getAuth().uid; // Throws error

      // Define our path
      var path = uid + '/programs/' + key;

      // Fetch the program from Firebase
      var program = fbRefs.getSyncedObj(path).$loaded();

      return program;
    }]
  }
})
```

Added `states` service code by request:

```
auth.service('states', [function() {

  var auth;

  return {
    getAuth: function() {
      return auth;
    },
    setAuth: function(state) {
      auth = state;
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Be aware that a common answer to "i dont want to show half-rendered templates" is to display a scrim over the elements in question with a loading message, and hide the scrim programmatically after you have got your data

Comment: I think it would be helpful to include the code for the `states` service

Comment: @jnishiyama Added states code

Comment: @Plato I am aware of that but it would be more work than necessary in this scenario. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: the `auth` returned by getAuth is undefined and so will not have a uid property, try `var auth = {uid: null}` or otherwise set auth.uid before you try and resolve. I usually do something like `var auth = $('body').data('myJsonTokenAttribute')` with `<body data-myJsonTokenAttribute="{}">` (be aware this could be MITM'd if you dont use SSL)

Comment: Do you set `auth` earlier in your code?

Comment: @jnishiyama Yes, you need to be logged in to even get to the view I'm working on. If auth is undefined I get redirected to the login screen, which I'm not now. It's only in my resolve which it fails.

Comment: What is fbRefs.getAuthObj()? Why all this indirection on top of the AngularFire services? Since $firebaseAuth() has a $getAuth() method, which is always available, there's also no reason to have an error-prone getAuth()/setAuth() state service.

Comment: @Kato Didn't know you could do it that way directly, works now but I can't seem to inject programData into my controller.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the 'Service Recipe' to create the `states` service, but returning like a 'Factory Recipe'.

According to the doc:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#service-recipe

You should either use this:

```
auth.factory('states', [function() {

  var auth;

  return {
    getAuth: function() {
      return auth;
    },
    setAuth: function(state) {
      auth = state;
    }
  };
}]);
```

Or this:

```
auth.service('states', [function() {

  var auth;

  this.getAuth = function() {
      return auth;
  };

  this.setAuth = function(state) {
      auth = state;
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I still get undefined.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Can you try to create a fiddle or something? Or could you `console.log()` your `states` to see what actually happens?